# How do I check functions that should never return false?

Tags: php, error-handling, controller

**Background:**

Inside large controllers I will have a number of different functions being called, to create a user, to update their order, to schedule in an event. Each of these operations are handled by a function in the model layer... here is an example of one of those functions:

```
$user_id = 1;
$data    = array('name' => 'Billy');

if (updateUser($user_id, $data) === false) {
    // handle error?
}

// continue with rest of controller
```

**Problem:**

I finally took a reality check today and realised that I have no good reason for coding like this...

If `updateUser()` returns false then something has seriously gone wrong with my Database Abstraction Layer that has prevented me from updating data in my database. This should never happen and therefore there are no practical errors to show my users anyway (that would allow them to take appropriate actions).

Basically my app is fundamentally broken at that point.

**Question:**

Should I bother to check functions that ***should*** never return false? If so how? Or should I just call them like this without any checks?

```
updateUser($foo)
createBooking($bar)
scheduleEvent($qux)
```

Comment: _"This should never happen"_ - Sure, but it still _can_ happen (db server goes down, the connection temporarily get's disconnected for some weird reason etc.). If that happens, don't you want show the user that something went wrong and ask them to try again? Never assume that your code/server/system won't have bugs/issues. jeroen's answer below is the correct way of handling it.

Comment: That makes sense! I should probably look into an error logging package.

Comment: ...and work with Exceptions (which are just what they say, exceptions from the normal flow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When something happens inside a function that should never happen, throw an [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

And then you can handle (catch) all exceptions where you want to do that. For example by showing a friendly message to the user and logging all details for yourself so that you know what went wrong and where.

Then you can get rid of the `if` statements and only use these when there are valid / normal options.